# Masonry gallery block is working in the block editor but not the template editor

Tags: javascript, block-editor, masonry, react

I'm building a custom Masonry (non-jQuery version) gallery block and I managed to make it work in the block editor. I'm using WP 6.3. This is roughly the code:

**JS:**

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const {
    attributes: { items, columns, gap },
    setAttributes,
} = props;

useEffect(() => {
    var msnry;
    if (containerRef.current) {
        imagesLoaded(containerRef.current, function () {
            msnry = new Masonry(containerRef.current, {
                itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                percentPosition: true,
                gutter: parseInt(gap),
            });
        });
    }

    return () => {
        msnry?.destroy();
    }

}, [items, columns, gap]);

....

const displayItems = (items) => {
    return (
        items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <div className="gallery-item" key={index}>
                    <figure>
                        <img className={`wp-image-${item.id}`} src={item.url} alt={item.alt} key={item.id} />
                    </figure>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
};

{items.length > 0 ?
    <div {...blockProps}>
        <div className="gallery-items" style={{ '--gap': gap }} ref={containerRef}>
            <div className="grid-sizer"></div>
            {displayItems(items)}
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**SCSS:**

```
.wp-block-my-masonry-gallery {
    .gallery-items {
        --gap: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: var(--gap);
    }
    @for $i from 2 through 8 {
        &.columns-#{$i} {
            .gallery-item,
            .grid-sizer {
                width: calc(percentage(math.div(1, $i)) - var(--gap) + (var(--gap) / $i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**block.json**

```
{
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "my/masonry-gallery",
    "title": "My Masonry Gallery",
    "attributes": {
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        },
        "columns": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 1,
            "maximum": 8,
            "default": 3
        },
        "gap": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "10px"
        }
    },
    "editorScript": [
        "file:./index.js",
        "imagesloaded",
        "masonry"
    ],
    "viewScript": [
        "file:./view.js",
        "imagesloaded",
        "masonry"
    ],
    "style": [
        "file:./style-index.css",
        "file:./view.css"
    ],
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css"
}
```

As I said before, the block works in the block editor, but when I try it in the new FSE template editor, the Masonry lib is not initialized correctly as the height of the Masonry container is set to zero and therefore the gallery images are overlapping the next blocks in the screen.

**Block in the block editor:**

[image]

**Block in the FSE template editor:**

[image]

Someone pointed me to the following post that mentions that the template editor is loaded in an iframe to isolate it from the rest of the admin screen and might cause issues with non-React libraries and suggest some changes to make them work in the iframed editor:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/blocks-in-an-iframed-template-editor/

I refactored the code following the examples in the post but I’m getting the same results as before:

```
const containerRef = useRefEffect((element) => {
    var msnry;
    imagesLoaded(element, function () {
        msnry = new Masonry(element, {
            itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            percentPosition: true,
            gutter: parseInt(gap),
        });
    });

    return () => {
        msnry?.destroy();
    }

}, [items, columns, gap]);
```

Following @stokesman suggestions, I refactored the code to the following with no success:

```
const containerRef = useRefEffect((element) => {
    var msnry;
    
    const { ownerDocument } = element;
    const { defaultView } = ownerDocument;

    if ( ! defaultView.imagesLoaded || ! defaultView.Masonry ) {
        return;
    }

    defaultView.imagesLoaded(element, function () {
        msnry = new defaultView.Masonry(element, {
            itemSelector: '.gallery-item',
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            percentPosition: true,
            gutter: parseInt(gap),
        });
    });

    return () => {
        msnry?.destroy();
    }

}, [items, columns, gap]);
```

The `if ( ! defaultView.imagesLoaded || ! defaultView.Masonry )` check never evaluates to `false` and the Masonry part is never executed.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE (02/20/2024):**

In order to inject the masonry and imagesloaded scripts into the iframe so they could be used from within the iframe, you must add them to the `script` prop (not the `editorScript` prop) in the `block.json` file. Otherwise, they are loaded OUTSIDE the iframe for some reason.

```
...
"script": [
    "imagesloaded",
    "masonry"
],
"editorScript": "file:./index.js",
"viewScript": "file:./view.js",
...
```

Comment: Is there any errors in the console? Without some idea of what the error is this a shot in the dark but the last section of that article mentions using the script from within the iframe. So in your case instead of `new Masonry(…` it’d be something like: `new element.ownerDocument.defaultView.Masonry(…` but you'd want some optional chaining or null checks in there as demonstrated in the article.

Comment: No errors in the console with my code. But, If I change it to `element.ownerDocument.defaultView.imagesLoaded` and `element.ownerDocument.defaultView.Masonry` like you suggested I get an `Uncaught TypeError: s.imagesLoaded is not a function` error in the console.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough about the null check. On a line before the `imagesLoaded` call I'd put this `if ( ! defaultView.imagesLoaded || ! defaultView.Masonry ) return;`. That assumes you've assigned `const { defaultView } = element.ownerDocument;` on a line before that. As stated in the last code example in that article: "Scripts are loaded asynchronously, so check that the script is loaded. After the dependencies have loaded, the block will re-render."

Comment: I added that check to my code but then the code after it it's never executed. It seems both conditions evaluate to `undefined` and never change to `true`.

Comment: Added refactored code to my original post for reference.

Comment: Okay, looks good. I am now suspecting that when that article says: "We’ve loaded all front-end scripts in the iframe to fix these cases," they mean that's done only in the post editor and not FSE/template editor. That would explain why those vars are never get defined. Does it ever execute in the post editor then? Though for the test to matter you'll have to be sure the post editor is using the iframe. Your block.json has `apiVersion: 2` and that needs to be 3 in order to use the iframed editor. All registered blocks have to be > 2 or else you won't be getting the iframed editor.

Comment: Sorry, in my original post it says `apiVersion: 2` but I already changed it to 3 in all my recent tests. According to the make post, the template editor is the only that has been iframed: "While the new template editor has been iframed, the post editor remains unchanged. We do this to gradually test how existing blocks from plugins work within an iframed editor, since there are cases where a block could look broken or (less likely) error."

Comment: I changed the `apiVersion` to 3 in my original post

Comment: Yes, and starting with 6.3 even the post editor is iframed unless some registered blocks have `apiVersion < 3` (or custom fields or other legacy metaboxes are displayed). I take it the refactored version no longer works even in the post editor? I've been doing a little experimenting and it seems like "We’ve loaded all front-end scripts in the iframe to fix these cases" is no longer true. Anyway, this might not even be the cause of the problem. So when you said it was working in the post editor that was with `apiVersion: 3`?

Comment: Oops, I didn't know the iframed post editor was enabled in 6.3: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/18/miscellaneous-editor-changes-in-wordpress-6-3/#post-editor-iframed

Comment: Yes, the block is working with `apiVersion: 3` in the post editor, BUT, for some reason I'm not getting the iframed editor but the old non-iframed one, even though there are no other blocks in the page and custom fields are not displayed.

Comment: That's bizarre and I have no idea what else it could be. Anyway if it's not working when editing a template or in the tablet / mobile views than the result would probably be the same in the iframed post editor. I'd probably have to have a hand-on with it to figure out anything.

Comment: Yes, it's weird. Some condition here is failing: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a278aa2ac07e803f734fbb731a08ec2701276c80/wp-includes/js/dist/edit-post.js#L4248C17-L4248C17

Comment: If the Gutenberg plugin is enabled I get the iframed post editor, but not if it's disabled.

Comment: My fault, I had installed a block plugin with `apiVersion: 2` in my site. I disabled it and now I'm getting the iframed post editor, but the Masonry block no longer works as in the template editor.

Comment: Someone in another forum suggested me that the images might be loaded before the iframe is loaded, so the height calculation doesn’t work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't at fault. The Masonry library doesn't support this cross frame scenario. I can think of three ways you might get past this:

1. Inject the masonry script into the iframe so it could be used from within the iframe
2. Patch the masonry script and ship that version with your plugin
3. Find an alternative library that doesn't have the issue

The third option might be fruitless. I'm not sure there are many options out there and they might have the same sort of issues.

The second option I've tried. I patched a couple places in the library and it seems to work okay now. I'm not sure it's 100% covered i.e. you might encounter an issue with some configuration I haven't tried. Here’s a [gist with the patched version](https://gist.github.com/stokesman/b756d4e2f4e11d76aaa0c3faa76d4770) if you want to try it. In WordPress, you'll have to deregister the masonry script they bundled and register that one of course.

The first option might be a good one but you'd have to be sure to only try injecting the script into the iframe when there actually is one and you'd have to make sure your block waits to be sure the script has been made available in the iframe. There may be other potential gotchas as well.

On a side note, I'm considering submitting PRs to the libraries (the parts I patched are in separate dependencies (fizzy-ui-utils and outlayer) but not sure if/when they'd make it into a release.